# How to find mean and sd within df's groups?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'am struggle with one task: I have a dataframe, where one column is always numeric and others are always factors. I don't know the index of numeric columns.
My task is: to group dataframe by all factors, then to find mean and sd within each group.
I have already done some part of work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
df <-  data.frame(
  col1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  col2 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  col3 = rnorm(100))
df
find_mean_sd <- function(df){
  numeric <- which(sapply(df,is.numeric)==TRUE)
  columns <- names(df)[-numeric]
  dots <- lapply(columns, as.symbol)
  df %>%
    group_by_(.dots=dots) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(df[,numeric]), SD= sd(df[,numeric]))
}
find_mean_sd(df)
```

I am confused with mean and sd: why do they the same for all groups? I wanted to get 9 different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to fix your code, you can try this:

```
 library(dplyr)
 find_mean_sd <- function(df){
    numeric <- which(sapply(df,is.numeric)==TRUE)
    columns <- names(df)[-numeric]
    dots <- lapply(columns, as.symbol)
    df %>%
      group_by_(.dots=dots) %>%
      summarise_all(funs(mean,sd))  # here you can summarise by the functions you need
  }

  find_mean_sd(df)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   col1 [3]
  col1  col2     mean    SD
  <fct> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     A      0.202  1.19 
2 A     B     -0.141  0.950
3 A     C      0.585  0.596
4 B     A     -0.0812 1.20 
5 B     B     -0.380  1.18 
6 B     C      0.300  0.846
7 C     A     -0.152  0.705
8 C     B      0.136  1.39 
9 C     C      0.263  0.762
```

I think the problem was that you use in a `dplyr` chain the `df`, that is not necessary in the part of the `summarise` for your purpose, despite the A. Suliman solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::*_if` to select the required columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by_if(is.factor) %>% 
   summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean=~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), SD=~sd(.,na.rm = TRUE)))
```